# What is another way to say 'to keep tabs on someone'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a word to describe keeping track of someone? To know where they are and what they're doing, being completely responsible for them.

Comment: Er... ***tracking*** them? What did you find when you looked up *track (v.)* in a thesaurus?

Comment: Keeping tabs on someone and responsibility are not the same.

Comment: Being the parent of a five-year-old rascal.

Comment: @Helmar No, but a word can mean both.

Comment: Keep them under surveillance?

Answer (score 1):

[**Keep an eye on**](https://www.google.com/#q=keep%20an%20eye%20on) **-** keep under careful observation

---

Or, if you only want a single word:

[**Supervise**](https://www.google.com/#q=supervise+definition) **-** keep watch over (someone) in the interest of their or others' security.
This one also covers being responsible.  For example:

> Camp counselors must supervise their campers; it's their job to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

To **monitor**.

> *monitor* (v t) 14. to watch closely for purposes of control,
>   surveillance, etc.; keep track of.

[[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monitor)]

Often used with a non-sentient object, but 97,700 Google hits for 'monitored him'.

Answer (score 0):

I will offer three options, in a continuum, the last one being the strongest.

> Shadow the person.
>
> Stick with the person, or stick to the person like glue.
>
> Not let the person out of your sight.

Answer (score 0):

May I propose the words surveillance (noun) and surveil (verb).

"We needed to watch the suspect so our security services arranged for 24/7 *surveillance* but they were unable to *surveil* him at crucial moments of his day-to-day routine because he managed to evade our agents and disappear from our CCTV screens.

(Cambridge Dictionary). ***Surveillance ***. Noun - The careful watching of a person or place, especially by the police.

(Oxford Dictionary). **Surveil** - Verb - Keep (a person or place) under surveillance.